# Can't load JDBC driver class

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, jbossfuse

I create a simple Apache Camel application in JBoss Fuse server. 
My camel blueprint can't read the driver class.

This is the error message:

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver'
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver from bundle 144 (fer-cdr)
... 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver not found by jdbccamel
...
```

**This is the project structure:**

```
+-- Root
+== pom.xml
+-- jdbccamel (Maven Module)
|   +-- pom.xml
|   +-- /src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml
+-- features (Maven Modul => contains fabric feature of the project)
|   +-- pom.xml
|   +-- scr/main/resources/features.xml
```

**pom.xml (jdbccamel)**

```
....
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.maven-bundle-plugin}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Include-Resource>{maven-resources}</Include-Resource>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
....
```

**pom.xml (features)**

```
....
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifacts>
                            <artifact>
                                <file>target/features/features.xml</file>
                                <type>xml</type>
                                <classifier>features</classifier>
                            </artifact>
                        </artifacts>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
....
```

**features.xml (features)**

```
....
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features name="myfeature" xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.0.0">
    <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.assemblies.features/standard/2.3.0.redhat-60024/xml/features</repository>
    <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.assemblies.features/enterprise/2.3.0.redhat-60024/xml/features</repository>
    <repository>mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/2.7.10/xml/features</repository>
    <repository>mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.12.3/xml/features</repository>
    <repository>mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-karaf/5.8.0.redhat-60024/xml/features</repository>
    <feature name="fer-cdr">
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.3</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:commons-pool/commons-pool/1.4</bundle>
        <feature version="2.12.3">camel-core</feature>
        <feature version="2.12.3">camel-blueprint</feature>
        <feature version="2.12.3">camel-jdbc</feature>
        <feature version="(3.1,4.0]">spring-jdbc</feature>
        <bundle>mvn:com.project/jdbccamel/1.5.9</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
....
```

**blueprint.xml(jdbccamel)**

```
....
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${cdr.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${cdr.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${cdr.password}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="${cdr.initialSize}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="${cdr.maxActive}" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="${cdr.testOnBorrow}" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="${cdr.validationQuery}" />
</bean>
....
```

My findings:
When i import-package in the maven-bundle-plugin (see pom.xml in jdbccamel)

```
<Import-Package>oracle.jdbc.driver</Import-Package>
```

like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.maven-bundle-plugin}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Include-Resource>{maven-resources}</Include-Resource>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource class won't load and i get message like this:

```
org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve dummy/0.0.0: missing requirement [dummy/0.0.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=jdbccamel; type=karaf.feature; version=0 [caused by: Unable to resolve jdbccamel/0.0.0: missing requirement [jdbccamel/0.0.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=jdbccamel; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.5.9,1.5.9]" [caused by: Unable to resolve jdbccamel/1.5.9: missing requirement [jdbccamel/1.5.9] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource)"]]
  at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates.populateResource(Candidates.java:285)
  at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates.populate(Candidates.java:153)
  at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:148)
  at io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentBuilder.resolve(DeploymentBuilder.java:231)
  at io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentAgent.doUpdate(DeploymentAgent.java:567)
  at io.fabric8.agent.DeploymentAgent$2.run(DeploymentAgent.java:293)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When i add both, like this:

```
<Import-Package>oracle.jdbc.driver,org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource</Import-Package>
```

It can't load JDBC driver like before.

Comment: [SOLVED] the problem is setting the driver class `oracle.jdbc.driver` instead of `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

Answer (score 0):

This does not work well in OSGi. The BasicDataSource tries to resolve the oracle classes using its own classloader that does not see these classes.

The simplest approach is to use the [OracleDataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html). In this case there is no classloader magic involved and it should work. Your bundle will also get the Import-Package statements automatically as you directly reference the class.

A better approach is to use pax-jdbc. Pax-jdbc provides wrappers for most databases and helps them publish a DataSourceFactory which is the OSGi standard to access databases.

[Pax-jdbc-config](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/Create+DataSource+from+config) allows to create a DataSource from the DataSourceFactory by using a plain config. It also allows to use several pooling libs.

For a small example see this [example](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/liquibase). You can just leave out the liquibase part if you do not need it.